Refactoring Python Code for Mouse and Keyboard Actions with Pynput
I have a script that uses the pynput library to perform a series of mouse and keyboard actions. The script highlights certain areas on the screen, copies the highlighted content, and saves it to variables. It also includes specific sleep times for each action to ensure the script runs correctly.
Here's my code:
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from time import sleep
import clipboard

# Define the controller
mouse_controller = mouse.Controller()
keyboard_controller = keyboard.Controller()

# Define the action of highlighting from A to B and save to C
def highlight_and_save(A, B):
    sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay before the process
    # Move the mouse to position A
    mouse_controller.position = A
    sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
    # Press the left button
    mouse_controller.press(mouse.Button.left)
    sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
    # Move the mouse to position B
    mouse_controller.position = B
    sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
    # Release the left button
    mouse_controller.release(mouse.Button.left)
    sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
    # Press ctrl+C to copy the highlighted content
    with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
        keyboard_controller.press('c')
        keyboard_controller.release('c')
    sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay after the process
    # Get the content from clipboard
    C = clipboard.paste()
    return C

# Define the action when the user press and released the key "q"
def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('q'):
        # Press and release the "ctrl"+"0" to make the page in 100%
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('0')
            keyboard_controller.release('0')
        # Start highlighting from (158, 693) to (218,693) and save to "主办机构 checker"
        主办机构_checker = highlight_and_save((158, 693), (218,693))
        # Click at (218,693) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (218,693)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # If the value saved of "主办机构 checker" is equals to "主办机构" string
        if 主办机构_checker == "主办机构":
            # Highlight (297,695) to (454,695), and save to "主办机构" variable
            Presenter_SC = highlight_and_save((297, 698), (862, 692))
            # Click at (454,695) to deselect the highlighted area
            mouse_controller.position = (454,695)
            mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Highlight from (379, 248) to (1509, 326) and save to "Event Title (SC)" variable
        Event_Title_SC = highlight_and_save((379, 248), (1509, 326))
        # Click at (1509, 326) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (1509, 326)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Highlight from (1073, 435) to (438, 430) and save to "Venue (SC)" variable
        Venue_SC = highlight_and_save((1073, 435), (438, 430))
        # Click at (438, 430) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (1386, 274)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Move from (1098, 160) to (1109, 223) and click once
        mouse_controller.position = (1098, 160)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        mouse_controller.position = (1109, 223)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Wait for 5 seconds
        sleep(5)



        # Start highlighting from (158, 693) to (218,693) and save to "主辦機構 checker"
        主辦機構_checker = highlight_and_save((158, 693), (218,693))
        # Click at (218,693) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (218,693)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # If the value saved of "主辦機構 checker" is equals to "主辦機構" string
        if 主辦機構_checker == "主辦機構":
            # Highlight (297,695) to (454,695), and save to "主辦機構" variable
            Presenter_TC = highlight_and_save((297, 698), (862, 692))
            # Click at (454,695) to deselect the highlighted area
            mouse_controller.position = (454,695)
            mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Highlight from (379, 248) to (1509, 326) and save to "Event Title (TC)" variable
        Event_Title_TC = highlight_and_save((379, 248), (1509, 326))
        # Click at (1509, 326) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (1509, 326)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Highlight from (1073, 435) to (438, 430) and save to "Venue (TC)" variable
        Venue_TC = highlight_and_save((1073, 435), (438, 430))
        # Click at (438, 430) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (1386, 274)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Move from (1098, 160) to (1109, 223) and click once
        mouse_controller.position = (1098, 160)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        mouse_controller.position = (1098, 299)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Wait for 5 seconds
        sleep(5)
        
        # Start highlighting from (158, 693) to (218,693) and save to "Presenter checker"
        Presenter_checker = highlight_and_save((158, 693), (245, 699))
        # Click at (218,693) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (218,693)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # If the value saved of "Presenter checker" is equals to "Presenter" string
        if Presenter_checker == "Presenter":
            # Highlight (297, 698) to (862, 692), and save to "Presenter" variable
            Presenter_EN = highlight_and_save((297, 698), (862, 692))
            # Click at (454,695) to deselect the highlighted area
            mouse_controller.position = (454,695)
            mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Highlight from (379, 248) to (1509, 326) and save to "Event Title (EN)" variable
        Event_Title_EN = highlight_and_save((379, 248), (1509, 326))
        # Click at (1509, 326) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (1509, 326)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Highlight from (1073, 435) to (438, 430) and save to "Venue (EN)" variable
        Venue_EN = highlight_and_save((1073, 435), (454, 436))
        # Click at (438, 430) to deselect the highlighted area
        mouse_controller.position = (1386, 274)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Click at (366, 640)
        mouse_controller.position = (366, 640)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        Price_unclean = highlight_and_save((874, 698), (294, 698))
        # Suppose Price_unclean is in the form of "$120/$60"
        # Remove the dollar sign
        Price_unclean = Price_unclean.replace("$", "")
        # Split the string into a list of prices
        prices = Price_unclean.split("/")
        # Convert the prices to integers
        prices = [int(price) for price in prices]
        # Get the minimum price
        cleaned_price = min(prices)

        # Click at (574, 65)
        mouse_controller.position = (574, 65)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Press and release ctrl+C to copy the text
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('c')
            keyboard_controller.release('c')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay to ensure the content is copied
        # Save the copied text into a variable called "URL"
        URL = clipboard.paste()

        # Click at (290, 18)
        mouse_controller.position = (290, 18)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)
        # Paste the URL
        clipboard.copy("https://app.1m1a.org/cccms/event/add")
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        # Press enter
        keyboard_controller.press(keyboard.Key.enter)
        keyboard_controller.release(keyboard.Key.enter)
        sleep(10)
        # Move the mouse cursor to (854, 247)
        mouse_controller.position = (854, 247)
        sleep(3)
        # Scroll down 5 units
        mouse_controller.scroll(0, -5)
        sleep(3)
        # Click at (522, 302)
        mouse_controller.position = (522, 302)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        # Paste the string: "Presenter variable" + " " + Event_Title_EN
        clipboard.copy(f'{Presenter_EN} "{Event_Title_EN}" ')
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)
        # Click at (1065, 310)
        mouse_controller.position = (1065, 310)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)
        # Paste the string: "主辦機構 variable" + " " + Event_Title_TC
        clipboard.copy(f'{Presenter_TC} 《{Event_Title_TC}》 ')
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)
        # Click at (1236, 330)
        mouse_controller.position = (1236, 330)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)
        # Paste the string: "主办机构 variable" + " " + Event_Title_SC
        clipboard.copy(f'{Presenter_SC} 《{Event_Title_SC}》 ')
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)

        # Move the mouse cursor to (854, 247)
        mouse_controller.position = (854, 247)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Scroll down 4 units
        mouse_controller.scroll(0, -4)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay

        # Click at (608, 456)
        mouse_controller.position = (608, 456)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay


        # Move the mouse cursor to (854, 247)
        mouse_controller.position = (854, 247)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Scroll down 4 units
        mouse_controller.scroll(0, -4)
        sleep(1)  # Add a small delay

        # Click at (994, 401)
        mouse_controller.position = (994, 401)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Paste the string: Venue_EN
        clipboard.copy(Venue_EN)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay

        # Click at (991, 519)
        mouse_controller.position = (991, 519)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Paste the string: Venue_TC
        clipboard.copy(Venue_TC)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay

        # Click at (1055, 633)
        mouse_controller.position = (1055, 633)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Paste the string: Venue_SC
        clipboard.copy(Venue_SC)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Click at (653, 284)
        mouse_controller.position = (653, 284)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        # Click at (622, 578)
        mouse_controller.position = (622, 578)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)

        # Paste the string: cleaned_price
        # Click at (454, 746)
        mouse_controller.position = (454, 746)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy(cleaned_price)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Paste the string: cleaned_price
        # Click at (819, 746)
        mouse_controller.position = (819, 746)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy(cleaned_price)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Paste the string: cleaned_price
        # Click at(1203, 745)
        mouse_controller.position =(1203, 745)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy(cleaned_price)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Scroll down 6 units
        mouse_controller.scroll(0, -6)
        sleep(0.5)  # Add a small delay
        # Click at (366, 252)
        mouse_controller.position = (366, 252)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy("Buy Now")
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (741, 250)
        mouse_controller.position = (741, 250)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy("立即購票")
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (1154, 245)
        mouse_controller.position = (1154, 245)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy("立即购票")
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (381, 357)
        mouse_controller.position = (381, 357)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (349, 471)
        mouse_controller.position = (349, 471)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (390, 705)
        mouse_controller.position = (390, 705)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy(URL)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (876, 710)
        mouse_controller.position = (876, 710)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy(URL)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
        # Click at (1150, 708)
        mouse_controller.position = (1150, 708)
        mouse_controller.click(mouse.Button.left, 1)
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        clipboard.copy(URL)
        with keyboard_controller.pressed(keyboard.Key.ctrl):
            keyboard_controller.press('v')
            keyboard_controller.release('v')
        sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay
        
# Listen to the keyboard
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()


I have tried to refactor the code by creating a function highlight_and_save to avoid repeating the same sequence of actions. This function takes two points as parameters, highlights the area between these points, copies the content, and saves it to a variable. This has significantly reduced the redundancy in my code.
However, I am still not satisfied with the length and readability of the script. I am looking for ways to further simplify it without losing the important details such as sleep times, positions, and the saving process. I am also interested in accommodating subtle differences in coordinates for other languages.
My expectation is to have a more concise and readable script, ideally with fewer lines of code. I am open to using different libraries or functions that can perform equivalent actions. I am also interested in any algorithms that could simplify this task. My ultimate goal is to minimize the number of characters in the script while preserving its functionality.
I hope this clarifies my attempts and expectations. I look forward to any suggestions on how to improve my code. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Of course there are many things in the code that can be improved as you mentioned. For one, using a mouse and keyboard controlling library to copy and save text is very inefficient. Instead, by getting the coordinates of the text, screenshotting that, and using a python library to read the text using something like pytesseract, is way more efficient. I also want to note that having positions in your code makes the code harder to maintain, if the position of the text changes, you'll have to go back all the way through the code and change the positions.

Perhaps this question would be better suited to code review, however be sure to read their how-to-ask page.
